# Use older version of google app engine on appspot

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am using google app engine sdk 1.8.6 for python and it works fine on localhost.
But recently google has switched to sdk 1.8.7 due to which my app is not working properly.
Locally it raises HTTPError: `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

Is there any way in which we can use a previous version on appspot.com.

This is my stacktrace  for SDK 1.8.7 
(Note) the same app works fine when using SDK 1.8.6

```
URLError(error(2, 'No such file or directory'),)
URLError(error(2, 'No such file or directory'),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
INFO     2013-11-09 06:30:25,630 module.py:608] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 269, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/request_rewriter.py", line 311, in _rewriter_middleware
    response_body = iter(application(environ, wrapped_start_response))
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/request_handler.py", line 97, in __call__
    self._flush_logs(response.get('logs', []))
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/request_handler.py", line 233, in _flush_logs
    apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall('logservice', 'Flush', request, response)
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 94, in MakeSyncCall
    return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 328, in MakeSyncCall
    rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 156, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 200, in MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 226, in _MakeRealSyncCall
    encoded_response = self._server.Send(self._path, encoded_request)
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 409, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 2] No such file or directory>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 269, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/request_rewriter.py", line 311, in _rewriter_middleware
    response_body = iter(application(environ, wrapped_start_response))
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/request_handler.py", line 97, in __call__
    self._flush_logs(response.get('logs', []))
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/request_handler.py", line 233, in _flush_logs
    apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall('logservice', 'Flush', request, response)
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 94, in MakeSyncCall
    return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 328, in MakeSyncCall
    rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 156, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 200, in MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 226, in _MakeRealSyncCall
    encoded_response = self._server.Send(self._path, encoded_request)
  File "/home/rocker/CloudAppGCDC/sdk/gg/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 409, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 2] No such file or directory>
```

I don't understand why is it working in sdk 1.8.6 and not sdk 1.8.7.

Comment: Could it be related to the recent problems the GAE production environment was having with urlfetch? All GAE users should subscribe to google-appengine-downtime-notify

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no way.  The production runtime is upgraded by google and you have no control at all.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP errors are passed through from the site your app is trying to access via `urlfetch`. This mostly likely has nothing to do with an SDK update.

If you suspect otherwise, please show us a stacktrace, the code you're using, and the site you're trying to access.

Comment: I have added the stacktrace.

Comment: i am just trying to access localhost:8080/ when it throws this error.

Comment: i even tried running the basic helloworld application.. That is alo showing the same error.